# Checking if a key exists in a Hbase table affects subsequent get call

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I'm sure am overlooking something in the snippet below, but I can't figure out what. As indicated, if I include a call to 'exists' to quickly check if the key exists in table, the subsequent 'get' ends up returning nothing; commenting out the 'exists' call, however, makes the code work. But, now I have to do additional checks before parsing the result fetched from Hbase to make sure it is not empty/null.

```
...
final Get g = new Get(someKey);
g.setCacheBlocks(true);
g.setMaxVersions(1);
g.addColumn(colFamily, colName);


/* --- THIS DOES NOT WORK --- */
if (this.someHbaseTab.exists(g)) {
    final Result res = this.someHbaseTab.get(g);
    // res is empty!!!
}
// --- --- ---

/* --- THIS WORKS --- */
// No call to 'exists'
final Result res = this.someHbaseTab.get(g);
// Valid result
// --- --- ---
...
```

I'm running Cloudera CDH5.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to call exists. Just check `res.isEmpty()` after the `get()` call